# How to list multiple records in an .asp classic page

Tags: database, asp-classic, vbscript, insert, records

[Database screenshot](http://i49.tinypic.com/2yxem3k.png)

This is a database that i am trying to link to a .asp classic page. I was wondering if there was a way to enter multiple records into the same .asp page and/or to enter a specific record into the page if needed to. Im using ASP VBScript. Note that i am trying to get the data from a database (.mdb/.accdb) file.

Comment: Sure there is a way. You need to open a connection to the database and fetch the rows you want to display. What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far ive done nada because the testing server of the free hosting website im give has been down for a while

Comment: i can grab the first record set to the asp page but i dont know how to get the specific one i need or the next one. Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

b_use_dsn = false   
if (b_use_dsn=false) then
    'SQL_server_string = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=myMachine; Initial Catalog=pubs; User ID=sa; Password="
    path_to_db = application("path_to_db")
    if (path_to_db = "") then path_to_db = "../data"
    Access_string = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.mappath(path_to_db) & "/hotkey.mdb"
else
    Access_string = "DSN=casemodo"
end if
ConnectionString = Access_string
conn.Open ConnectionString

s_table = request.querystring("s_table")
if (s_table="") then s_table = session("s_table")
session("s_table") = s_table

ID_page = request.querystring("ID_page")
if (isnull(ID_page) or ID_page="") then ID_page=session("ID_page")
if (isnull(ID_page) or ID_page="") then ID_page=0
session("ID_page") = ID_page

s_field_order = "i_order"
if (s_table="page_image_stack") then s_field_order = "i_build_image_layer DESC"

on error resume next
'open recordset
s = "SELECT"
s = s & " *"
s = s & " FROM " & s_table
if (ID_page<>"") then
s = s & " WHERE ID_page=" & ID_page
end if
s = s & " ORDER BY " & s_field_order
set rs=conn.execute(s)
if (err.number<>0) then
    if (err.number=-2147217904) then
        s = "SELECT"
        s = s & " *"
        s = s & " FROM " & s_table
        's = s & " ORDER BY ID"
        set rs=conn.execute(s)
    else
        msg = "Error on admin_data_show.asp line 26<hr>s=<br>" & s & "<hr>err.description=" & err.description & "<hr>err.number=" & err.number
        session("msg")=msg
        conn.close
        set conn=nothing
        response.redirect("error_report.asp?send_email=yes")
    end if
end if
i_columns = rs.fields.count

dim array_fields()
redim array_fields(i_columns)

for x=0 to i_columns-1
    s_name = rs(x).name
    array_fields(x) = s_name
    's_fields=s_fields & s_name & ","
    'n_columns = n_columns + 1
next

'Set rs = server.createObject("ADODB.recordset")
'rs.open s, conn, 0, 1 '0=forward only, 1=lock read only

s_main = "Secure Area"
s_title = "Manage data"
%>
<br>Table: <%=ucase(s_table)%>

<table border='0' width='<%=application("n_page_width")%>' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<td align='center' valign='middle'>
    <table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' valign='middle'>
        <br>
        <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' bgcolor='<%=application("s_color_bg_table")%>'>
<%
if (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) then
        Response.Write("<tr>")
        Response.Write("<td colspan='6' align='center'>")
        Response.Write("<table width='70%'>")
        Response.Write("<tr>")
        Response.Write("<td>")
        Response.Write("<br><b>There are no data.<br>Use the menu on the left to add one.</b><br><br>")
        Response.Write("</td>")
        Response.Write("</tr>")
        Response.Write("</table>")
        Response.Write("</td>")
        Response.Write("</tr>")
else
    response.write("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
    response.write("<td align='left' valign='bottom'>edit</td>")
    type_markers=0

    for x=0 to i_columns-1
        response.write("<td align='left' valign='bottom'>")
        s_field = array_fields(x)
        if (len(s_field)>2) then
            part_to_look_at = left(s_field,2)
            if (instr(1,part_to_look_at,"_",1)>0) then
                type_markers = 1
                s_caption = replace(right(s_field,len(s_field)-2),"_"," ")
            else
                s_caption = s_field 
            end if
        else
            s_caption = s_field         
        end if
        s_type=lcase(left(s_field,1)) 'this gives us "s" for string, "d" for date, etc
        response.write(s_caption)
        response.write("</td>" & vbCrLf)
    next
    response.write("<td align='left' valign='bottom'>del</td>") 
    response.write("</tr>" & vbCrLf)

    rs.movefirst
    do while not rs.EOF
        Response.Write("<tr>")

        Response.Write("<td class='small' align='left' valign='top'>")
        Response.Write("<a href='admin_data_add.asp?s_mode=edit&ID=" & rs(0) & "'><img src='images/btn_edit.png' border='0' alt='Edit " & rs(0) & " record'></a>")
        Response.Write("</td>")

        for x=0 to i_columns-1
            response.write("<td class='small' align='left' valign='top'>")
            response.write(rs(x))
            response.write("</td>" & vbCrLf)
        next


        Response.Write("<td class='small' align='left' valign='top'>")
        Response.Write("<a href='admin_data_delete.asp?ID=" & rs(0) & "'><img src='images/btn_delete.gif' border='0' alt='Delete this record'></a>")
        Response.Write("</td>")

        Response.Write("</tr>")

        rs.MoveNext
    loop
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
conn.close
set conn=nothing
%>
        </table>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
```

Comment: You have to actually read the code I gave you (rather than just paste it into your app) and change some things like, for example: s_table variable is needed. I have it set now so that s_table is read in via querystring. It is the name of your table. Also, if you are getting errors, post them here and we can help you find the problem.

Comment: Also, at the top I'm creating a database connection. You will need to customize my code there to fit your database setup.

Comment: You are most welcome! Did you notice in the database connection it is set up to look for an MDB file in a certain folder relative to the site's folder? Did you get that part working?